# Subtraction of within a list

Tags: python

i'm using Python and I have the following list  A = [10,20,30,40]
how can obtain a new list such as I'm adding the second element to the first, the third to the second and fourth to the third.  Meaning the output would be [30,50,70].

Answer (score 3):

Can use simple list comprehension like this:

```
a = [10,20,30,40]
b = [a[i] + a[i+1] for i in range(len(a)-1)]

b
[30, 50, 70]
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `pairwise` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from [the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) (which [will be added as a function of `itertools` in 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)). Once you've copied that, you can just do:

```
[x + y for x, y in pairwise(A)]
```

or for fun with less custom code, add imports `from operator import add` and `from itertools import starmap` and you can make an iterator that produces the results lazily with:

```
starmap(add, pairwise(A))  # Wrap in list if you need a list
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [10,20,30,40,50]
new_list = []
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    new_list.append(a[i] + a[i-1])
```

When we do `range(1, len(a))`, we create a set of indexes which are [1,2,3,4].

So when we do:
`for i in range(1, len(a)):` it's kind of like doing `for i in range [1,2,3,4]`.

If we now imagine we are doing:

```py
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
    new_list.append(a[i] + a[i-1])
```

What it's doing is getting the current value of `a` at `i` and adding it `a` at the previous index `i-1` and appending the result to a new list.

Comment: An explanation please?

Comment: I've updated the answer adding more detail.

Comment: Thanks for you help and explanation